# Multiple Checkbox Filter in PHP

Tags: php, sql, filter, checkbox

I have been trying to figure this out for a while, but am not getting anywhere with it. I have read a lot of the other questions posted here and across the internet but am not being able to find a solution. Specially in the case of using multiple checkboxes.

Please bear with me as I try to explain the problem I am facing.

On a page I have a list of People with their corresponding location which i pull from a database using php/sql. What I am trying to achieve is to be able to filter the list according to location using checkboxes.

This is the code I have currently for the checkboxes.

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="sydney">Sydney</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="durban">Durban</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="delhi">Delhi</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="cairo">Cairo</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="madrid">Madrid</li>
    <li><input type="submit"></li>
</ul>
```

This is the code I am using to check if a checkbox is checked and accordingly modify the SQL query

```
if (empty ($_POST['check_list'])) {

    $SQLquery = 'SELECT * FROM `people`';
    $query = $conn->query($SQLquery);

} elseif (!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {

    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check)

    $location = $check;

    $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `p_location` = :location');
    $query->execute(array('location' => $location));

}
```

Now this code works fine when only one checkbox is checked. However, when multiple checkboxes are checked this fails. It just shows nothing.

I know i can modify the SQL query using the `OR` operator to add other locations like so:

```
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `p_location` = 'Delhi' OR `p_location` = 'Madrid')
```

However, I am unable to figure out how I can first check which all checkboxes are checked and then create the SQL statement in a way which will filter the results when there is more than one city selected.

I am also wondering if this is the best way to achieve something like this or not. I am open to alternative ways of achieving this within the scope of php/sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but should give you an idea of what you should do.

ANSWER REVISED!

```
$markers = str_repeat('?, ', count($_POST['check_list']) - 1) . '?';

$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `p_location` IN (' . $markers . ')');
$query->execute($_POST['check_list']);
```

Comment: Can you really bind imploded values just like that ? You're adding a part of the SQL syntax inside the value to be binded, i'm not sure it works, and it looks dirty, imo.

Comment: Did not even think about that. Have to do some Googlin' around. ;)

Comment: @Damiqib Hi, thanks for your quick response. I tried implementing this but in vain. It works when a single checkbox is selected but fails when there are multiple selections.

Comment: @indrago Changed my answer, please test again.

Comment: @Damiqib Hey! Thanks! This works exactly how I wanted it to be. Thank you so much for taking the time to solve my problem. You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
where p_location in (the values for your checkboxes)
```

Comment: I am actually new to php and am not being able to figure it out on my own. I can implement the solution suggested by you when only one checkbox is selected. However, I have no idea how i can do the same for multiple selections

Comment: Actually he means something like this: where p_location in ('a','b','c') . You may want to use the php join() function to have a good comma separated list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
if (empty ($_POST['check_list'])) {

    $SQLquery = 'SELECT * FROM `people`';
    $query = $conn->query($SQLquery);

} else if (!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    $params = implode(",", array_fill(0, count($_POST['check_list']), "?"));

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `p_location` IN ($params)';

    $stmt   = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute($_POST['check_list']);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. However, this does not seem to be working. This is the error i get - `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'PDOStatement' does not have a method 'bindparams'`

Comment: @GDB Thank you for editing the code. I tried it out it it is still not working. However, the solution provided by Damiqib below worked. Anyway thank you for taking the effort and trying to help me out. Much appreciated.