# SQL query using checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I've seen some questions about this topic around here, but non of them solved my problem. I'm trying to make a simple filter using SQL and check boxes.

So far I got this code:

```
<form action="#" method="GET" id="filter"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="omgeving[]" value="Indoor">Indoor<br /> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="omgeving[]" value="Outdoor">Outdoor<br /> 
    <input type="submit" name="kies" value="Kies" /> 
</form>
```

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['omgeving']) && count($_GET['omgeving'] > 0)) { 
    $catid = implode(',', $_GET['omgeving']);
    $catid = mysql_real_escape_string($catid); 

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SomeWhere WHERE Omgeving IN (".$catid.")"); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
        $id = $row['Id']; 
        $prod = $row['Product']; 

        echo $prod . "<br />"; 
    }
}
?>
```

It does *something* when I click on `submit` it changes the URL to: `filtertest/?omgeving[]=Indoor&kies=Kies` but I think the query isn't working like it should because my footer disappears usually this means that my code is incorrect and the page stops loading further. For the love of me I cant figure out why this isn't working...

Is there someone that could help me?

I've checked out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123826/multiple-checkbox-filter-in-php) but this doesn't solve my problem. The code above is the code that does something at least.

Help...  what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [Exploits of a Mom](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom)

Comment: <form action="#"  <-- where is correct action script url?

Comment: Is it me or is there no action script needed if I just want the Query to be updated on the same page...

Comment: @Andreas nice one :'D, Jay-oh you should work a bit on the security http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Yeah, I know security is an issue here. I'm just trying to get the code to work, and after that worry about security. This site isn't live yet so I'm the only one using it right now :)

Comment: Have you been able to correct the issue

Comment: No I haven't... but this one is on hold for the moment. Thanks for asking though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `omgeving[]` to `omgeving`. so, the URL would be `?omgeving=Indoor&kies=Kies`

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['omgeving']) || !empty($_GET['omgeving'])){
  $catid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['omgeving']); 
  //continue with what you are doing.
  // use var_dump(<variable>); exit(); to debug.
}

?>
```

Hope it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
 $catid = implode(',', $_GET['omgeving']);
```

to

```
$catid = implode('","', $_GET['omgeving']);
$catid = '"'.$catid.'"';
```

Finally your query should look like below if you have multiple selected

SELECT * FROM SomeWhere WHERE Omgeving IN ("Indoor","Outdoor")

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work, did you get any error

Comment: No, no error. Only that the footer disappears like when I started... to bad.

Comment: Can you check the PHP  error log and show us the error log

Comment: Well, I don't exactly know how to show you an error log. As far as I can see I don't get an error. I added `error_log("You messed up!", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");` at the end of the script but that's probably wrong ...

Comment: Ubuntu - /var/log/apache2/error.log Centos -/var/www/logs/httpd/error_log

Answer (score -1):

$catid = implode("','", $_GET['omgeving']);